# How can I fix this error "invalid operands of types 'const char [17]' and 'float' to binary 'operator+'"?

Tags: mpu6050, error

```
#include <Wire.h>

long aX,aY,aZ,gX,gY,gZ;
float rtX,rtY,rtZ,gfX,gfY,gfZ;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  setupMPU ();
}

void loop()
{
  recordAccelregisters();
  recordGyroregisters();
  printData();
  delay(100);
}

void setupMPU()
{

  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000);
  Wire.write(0x6B);
  Wire.write(0b00000000);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000);
  Wire.write(0x1B);
  Wire.write(0b00000000);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000);
  Wire.write(0x1C);
  Wire.write(0b00000000);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}



void recordAccelregisters()
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000);
  Wire.write(0x3B);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(0b1101000,6);
  while(Wire.available()<6)
  {
    aX = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
    aY= Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
    aZ = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
    processAData();
  }
}

void processAData()
{
  gfX= aX/16384.0;
  gfY = aY/16384.0;
  gfZ = aZ/16384.0;
}

void recordGyroregisters()
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000);
  Wire.write(0x43);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(0b110100,6);
  while(Wire.available()>6)
  {
    gX = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
    gY = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
    gZ = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
    processGdata();
  }

}


void processGdata()
{
  rtX= gX/131.0;
  rtY = gY/131.0;
  rtZ= gZ /131.0;
}

void printData()
{
  Serial.print("Gyro degree(x)= "+ rtX + " ");// this line shows error mentioned above in the question
  Serial.print("Gyro degree(y)= "+ rtY + " ");// this line shows error mentioned above in the question
  Serial.print("Gyro degree(z)= "+ rtZ + " ");// this line shows error mentioned above in the question
  Serial.print("Accel Gforce(x)= "+ gfX + " ");// this line shows error mentioned above in the question
  Serial.print("Accel Gforce(y)= "+ gfY + " ");// this line shows error mentioned above in the question
  Serial.print("Accel Gforce(z)= "+ gfZ + " ");// this line shows error mentioned above in the question
}
```

this is a code of mpu6050.  Why am I getting this error and How Can I resolve it?

Comment: Side note: you should not write `Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read()` because [the order of evaluation of the calls to `Wire.read()` is unspecified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). See also [this thread in the Arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=659333.msg4443224#msg4443224). Use `gX=Wire.read()<<8;gX|=Wire.read();` instead.

Answer (score 3):

These lines give you errors, because you cannot simply add character arrays (aka c-strings) and floats together with the `+` operator. C/C++ is very strict, when it comes to variable types. The compiler does not know, how it should add these types together.

In other high level languages a string literal (characters enclosed by `"` in the source code) are more complex types, than c-strings. They mostly have various different methods and also an implementation of the `+` operator for adding a float number in human readable form. This complex type in the Arduino world is the `String` type. You can convert the float variable into a `String` and then add them together. But that's not the way, that you should do it. Strings on AVR based Arduinos (like Uno, Nano, ...) can be very evil due to the limited RAM. See Majenko's blog entry about [The Evils of Arduino Strings](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/) for more information.

Instead you should just use multiple print statements. As Serial data is send out serially (one byte after another), it doesn't matter, if you put all the data to send in one print statement, or in multiple onces. So each of the offending lines can be converted to something like this:

```
Serial.print("Gyro degree(x)= ");
Serial.print(rtX);
Serial.print(" ");
```

It does exactly, what your code does. But it will not produce an error, since the `Serial.print()` method is also implemented for using float arguments.